# What is the meaning of BPSK(n)

Tags: modulation, bpsk

I am doing some research into GNSS (Global Navigation Satellite Systems) and have come across various signals listed as having the in-phase or quadrature channels modulated with BPSK(2) or BPSK(10), etc.  However, I am struggling to find a definition of BPSK that includes this additional parameter.

What does the (n) signify in BPSK(n)?

I understand the basic concept of BPSK - Binary Phase Shift Keying and have implemented this in very basic tests by multiplying the LO by 1 or -1 for a 1 or 0 chip respectively.

It has been suggested by a colleague that the n is simply the chip rate and that BPSK(1) is a chip rate of 1MHz, BPSK(2) 2MHz, BPSK(10) 10MHz, etc. as mentioned in the comments by Jim Clay.

Comment: I am very familiar with BPSK, and I have never seen BPSK(n), BPSK(2), or BPSK(10).  Could you provide a quote that gives the context?

Comment: As a couple of examples, see the characteristics table in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beidou_Navigation_Satellite_System#Compass-M1 where various signals are described as BPSK(1) [GPS L1 C/A which is what I understood as BPSK], BPSK(2) or BPSK(10); or Figure 2 in http://www2.ulg.ac.be/ipne/garnir/time/galileo/gal_stf_final_paper.pdf

Comment: Both of those signals are CDMA.  A quick review didn't indicate explicitly what the numbers mean, but it appears to me that they probably indicate the chip rate that is used.  I saw a reference in a Galileo paper that seemed to suggest that BPSK(5) meant a BPSK signal at 5*fo chip rate.

Comment: Yuck, more tower of babel terminology rampant in the literature. ><

Comment: Yeah, and they don't even bother to define what they mean.

Comment: @Mohammad - and we all chose to do this because we love it :-)  When I was a kid, BPSK meant Binary Phase Shift Keying.  Them was the good old days for sure.

Comment: Sorry, but I find it a bit ironic to start a question about unexplained acronym, BPSK(n), with an unexplained acronym, GNSS.

Comment: Apologies for adding to the confusion.  GNSS = Global Navigation Satellite Systems.  E.g. GPS, GLONASS, Galileo, BeiDou, etc.

Comment: @BruceZenone Yes, us engineers are masochists of sorts! :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I do not have proof, it seems pretty clear, given the "Characteristics of Compass signals reported as of May 2008 compared to GPS-L1CA" table at the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beidou_Navigation_Satellite_System#Compass-M1) that you offered as an example, that the "(n)" notation refers to the chip rate.  You will notice that there is one BPSK(1) signal that has a chip rate of 1.023 Mchips/s.  There are four BPSK(2) signals listed, and all of them have a chip rate of 2.046 Mchips/s, which is twice 1.023 Mchips/s.  There are also three BPSK(10) signals that have a chip rate of 10.23 Mchips/s which is, of course, 10 times 1.023 Mchips/s.

It appears that the "(n)" notation means that the signal has a chip rate of $n*f_o$, and in the case of the Compass signals $f_o$ is 1.023 Mchips/s.